# Hacer una resta para sacar la edad actual de una persona

Tags: sql, postgresql

Necesito saber que función devuelve el año actual en pgadmin para sacar la edad actual de una persona.

Intenté hacer

```
YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - anio_nacimiento de la tabla persona.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Necesitas ocupar `date_part` pero en 2 momentos:

- Momento 1, es para sacar el año de la fecha actual que puedes obtener con `CURRENT_DATE`
- Momento 2, que es para sacar el año de la fecha que se tiene registrada, por ejemplo de nacimiento de tu usuario
- Finalmente restas la columna de la fecha reciente **menos** la columna de la fecha vieja  y eso te dará el total de años

*Consulta probada*

La consulta SQL debería quedar así:

```
SELECT date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE) - date_part('year', nacimiento) 
FROM tuTabla;
```

Muestra

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Referencias:

- [`date_part()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-datetime.html)

Comment: Solo como detalle, la edad actual debería calcularse con meses y dias, pues puede ser la época del año en que todavía no ha cumplido años de edad - 1, o ser la época de después del cumpleaños, indicando la edad

Answer (score 3):

Tienes una muy útil función para calcular años de vida: [`age()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html), la cual espera un `timestamp` de entrada para la fecha de nacimiento, por ejemplo:

```
select age(timestamp '19700602');

|                                              age |
|--------------------------------------------------|
| 49 years 5 mons 28 days 0 hours 0 mins 0.00 secs |
```

Si solo quieres los años:

```
select datepart('year', age(timestamp '19700602'));
```